# How to use a pointer to a templated type

Tags: c++, templates

I apologize for the beginner nature of this question.  I can't seem to get a pointer to a templated type to work.  For example, here is a header file:

```
#include "TemplatedClass.h"
using namespace std;
class PointList
{
public:
    PointList(TemplatedClass<Point> *p);
//snip
};
```

This doesn't seem to be legal.  What have I done wrong?  Thanks!

**edit** adding to  example.

```
//TemplatedClass.h
template <class T>
class TemplatedClass
{
public:
    TemplatedClass();
    TemplatedClass(T *t);
    TemplatedClass(const TemplatedClass &t);
    ~TemplatedClass();
    T *getNode() const;
    void setNode(T *t);
private:
    T *node;
};

//TemplatedClass.cpp
#include "TemplatedClass.h"
template <class T>
TemplatedClass<T>::TemplatedClass()
{
    node = 0;
};
template <class T>
TemplatedClass<T>::TemplatedClass(T *t)
{
    node = t;
};
template <class T>
TemplatedClass<T>::TemplatedClass(const TemplatedClass &l)
{
// snip
};
```

Comment: What is the compiler error you're getting?

Comment: Sounds like the compiler isn't recognizing the one or both of the names "TemplatedClass" or "Point".  Can you post a complete and minimal example?

Comment: Template clases are special. It is easier to put the 'TemplatedClass.cpp' content into the header file. Other alternatives are to rename it 'TemplatedClass.tpp' and directly include it from the header file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the definition of the Point class by including a header where that class is defined. For example :

```
#include "TemplatedClass.h"
#include "Point.h"   // if this header contains the Point's declaration
using namespace std;
class PointList
{
public:
    PointList(TemplatedClass<Point> *p);
//snip
};
```

**EDIT**

Actually, since your method takes a pointer, you can just forward declare :

```
template< typename T > class TemplatedClass;
class Point;
using namespace std;
class PointList
{
public:
    PointList(TemplatedClass<Point> *p);
//snip
};
```

but then in the source (cpp) file you need to include those headers

Comment: +1, nice to know you can have incomplete types as template parameters if the template is used as a pointer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to move all the member function template definitions from TemplatedClass.cpp to TemplateClass.hh. All the template definitions should be in header files (simplified).

Comment: He would get linker errors, but he is getting compiler errors